# T&C Checkbox IE Issue

Tags: internet-explorer, checkbox

I'm having an issue on the T&C checkbox in IE. Even if user did't checked the checkbox and they will still be able to pass through. FF & Chrome works fine. Only IE is facing this issue, please help me to have a look at the code.

```
<script> function accepttermandconditions() {
if(!accepttermandconditions_top()){ return false;}
<?php if($General->is_show_term_conditions()){?>
if(document.getElementById('termsandconditions').checked){
    return true;
}else{
    alert('<?php echo CHECKOUT_JS_TERMS_CONDITIONS_MSG;?>');
    document.getElementById('termsandconditions').focus();
    return false;
}
<?php
}
?>
if(!accepttermandconditions_bottom()){ return false;} }
```

Hope someone really can help me.

Thank you.

Comment: where did  you use jQuery here?? also show the only that html code which have t&c checkbox..

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, it sounds like IE is not executing your JavaScript.  The easiest way to find the answer is to debug it in IE.  If you're using IE8+, great, it has an excellent debugger built-in.  If using IE7 or less, then you'll need the Visual Studio debugger or the one that comes with Microsoft Office.

**EDIT: (Seen the page running now)**

You have this at the bottom of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
    if(eval(document.getElementById('coda-slider-1')))
    {
        $('#coda-slider-1').codaSlider();
        //jQuery.noConflict(); var $j = jQuery;
    }
}); 
</script>
```

Internet Explorer fails here at the start.  It says "Object doesn't support this property or method" - which is because $ is undefined.

Not sure why this is broken in IE only, because you have jQuery.noConflict() earlier in the page, which un-defines the $ object.  You should still be able to use jQuery().ready in the above script instead of $().ready.

Comment: I have tried to debug via the IE8 developer tool. But it seems like no error occur? This is what I see in the debugging tool

Comment: <div class="terms_condition clearfix">
   <input type="checkbox" name="termsandconditions" id="termsandconditions" class="checkin2" />&nbsp;
   <p><a href="/page_link/t_n_c.html" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'Terms & Conditions', 'resizable=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,fullscreen=no,scrollbars=yes,dependent=no,width=500,height=600'); return false;">Accept Terms and Conditions</a></p>   </div>

Comment: Hmm, that's not JavaScript debugging.  That's just a snippet of HTML.  If you have a link to the site (if it's already up), then I can see what's what myself.  How are you calling accepttermandconditions()?  Is it <form ... onsubmit="*return* accepttermandconditions()"> ?

Comment: I'm not sure how I'm calling it. By the way, I have uploaded my mirror site to the server, please help me to have a look. (http://110.4.45.145/~mozukoco/mirror/?ptype=checkout) simply register for an account and add something into the cart and proceed to that page, and you will be able to see the t&c checkbox. Hope you really can help me to solve this. Thank you.